# How to initialize an array to something in C without a loop?

Tags: c

Lets say I have an array like

```
int arr[10][10];
```

Now i want to initialize all elements of this array to 0. How can I do this without loops or specifying each element?

Please note that this question if for C

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The quick-n-dirty solution:

```
int arr[10][10] = { 0 };
```

If you initialise *any* element of the array, C will default-initialise any element that you don't explicitly specify. So the above code initialises the first element to zero, and C sets all the other elements to zero.

Comment: This will initialize all elements to 0? Why do you say its dirty?

Comment: Just to clarify: It doesn't "follow suit," it *forces* them to zero.

If you wrote `= { 1 };` it would put the first value as 1, and the rest would still be zeros.

Comment: I say quick-n-dirty because, even though it is logically correct and guaranteed to work, it may confuse maintainers. I consider it a shortcut, and avoid using it unless the array or data structure is too large to conveniently initialise every element.

Comment: Good point @Computer Guru; I didn't consider the ambiguity in my statement. I've amended it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the little-known `{0}`. It should be noted that the `{0}` initializer works for **any** type in the C language - integer types, floating point types, pointer types, array types (of any type), structures, unions, enums, you name it.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the initialization syntax, you can always `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(int)*10*10)`

Comment: Note that this still take O(N) time for N elements. On the other hand it is probably a faster O(N) than the one you code by hand (or at least no slower).

Comment: memset uses a loop, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `memset` might also be wrong for pointer or floating-point arrays.

Comment: Yes, it's technically O(n). It's unavoidable. The only way to set an arbitrary amount of bytes to the same value in constant time is with a very large magnet.

Comment: @Terry: Yes, unavoidable. I wasn't criticising your answer (indeed, you got my vote), but rather trying to prevent Shlemiel-the-painter problems for users of "high level" language users who may have understood this action as being a "single call" (I have see evidence of this issue on other posts on SO).

Comment: If you use any half-decent operating system and never call `free`, `calloc` stands a decent chance of being a "O(1) zero-fill" operation. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You're in luck: with 0, it's possible.

```
memset(arr, 0, 10 * 10 * sizeof(int));
```

You cannot do this with another value than 0, because `memset` works on bytes, not on `int`s. But an `int` that's all `0` bytes will always have the value `0`.

Comment: ... initializing all elements to -1. Good point, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: You can do it with any other value which, as bytes, consists of the same value in each byte. `n*(UINT_MAX+1ULL)/255` is the family of such values (`n`=0,1,...,`UCHAR_MAX`).

Answer (score 5):

```
int arr[10][10] = {0}; // only in the case of 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int myArray[2][2] = {};
```

You don't need to even write the zero explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: I think in C you have to write the zero (the empty braces are, however, valid C++).

Answer (score 0):

int arr[10][10] = { 0 };

Answer (score 0):

Defining a array globally will also initialize with 0.

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int ar[1000];
    
    int main(){


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: OP asked for C, this is C++