# Zero an array in C code

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to initialize an array to something in C without a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891191/how-to-initialize-an-array-to-something-in-c-without-a-loop)
>   [How to initialize an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

How can I zero a known size of an array without using a for or any other loop ?

For example:

```
arr[20] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
```

This is the long way... I need it the short way.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: Your "example" does not do what you think it does.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid C. Try posting something that compiles.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
int arr[20] = {0};
```

C99 `[$6.7.8/21]`

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size  than  there  are  elements  in  the  array,  **the  remainder  of  the  aggregate  shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

---

Comment: Does this also work for resetting, not initializing, the array?

Comment: Why not just `int arr[20] = {};` without the `0`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann because it's C, not C++.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav Nice one, but I guess it doesn't work for dynamic arrays

Comment: I think this doesn't make it clear that it doesn't copy the element in the brackets. So 
`float control[16] = {15.0};` is not an array with `15.0` copied 16 times, but is one `15.0`, and the rest is 0.

Comment: @WeihangJian I don't understand what's the point about being C or C++. in C I believe it's much more clear without the `0`, for the reason @DavidSullivan pointed out. It doesn't really makes sense to explicitly initialize the first element, while using default values for the others.

Comment: @pheki `T t = {} ;` is introduced since C++11 and they defined how it should be implemented, while the behavior is not defined in C standard and depends on each compiler's implementation.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: @WeihangJian It is actually defined in C, the quote in the answer (from C99 [$6.7.8/21]) is valid for both `{ 0 }` and `{ }`, since the array has 20 elements, specifying 1 or 0 elements are both ways to specify less initializers than there are members of the array. The value of the remaining elements is defined in C99 `[$6.7.8/10]`:

"If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then: - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;"

Answer (score 85):

```
int arr[20];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```

See the [reference for memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)

Comment: This can be wrong. You should either write `sizeof arr` or `20 * sizeof (int)`

Comment: I was confused at first, but then I remembered:
"If a type name is used, it must always be enclosed in parentheses, whereas expressions can be specified with or without parentheses"
 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)

Comment: @BarafuAlbino How sizeof(arr) can be wrong?

Comment: Could it be used for non-zero values as well? I tried it and it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 19):

Note: You can use memset with any character.

Example:

```
int arr[20];
memset(arr, 'A', sizeof(arr));
```

Also could be partially filled

```
int arr[20];
memset(&arr[5], 0, 10);
```

But be carefull. It is not limited for the array size, you could easily cause severe damage to your program doing something like this:

```
int arr[20];
memset(arr, 0, 200);
```

It is going to work (under windows) and zero memory after your array. It might cause damage to other variables values.

Comment: This is a perfect example of UB (undefined behaviour). The compiler can do whatever it likes when it comes across this, which usually means breaking stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Using `memset`:

```
int something[20];
memset(something, 0, 20 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Even better:
    int something[20];
    memset(something, 0, sizeof something);

Comment: unsure what OP wanted to ask, but he asked how to zero an array, not how to init, and this answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

`int arr[20] = {0}` would be easiest if it only needs to be done once.

Answer (score 1):

man bzero

```
NAME
   bzero - write zero-valued bytes

SYNOPSIS
   #include <strings.h>

   void bzero(void *s, size_t n);

DESCRIPTION
   The  bzero()  function sets the first n bytes of the byte area starting
   at s to zero (bytes containing '\0').
```

Comment: -1 *some more text from the man page:* ... This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs. ...

Comment: There is no header called strings.h in the C language. It is a (needless/pointless) non-standard compiler extension.